# Probability How many samples of five contian exactly one chip

Tags: probability

Hey guys I hav a task which I cannot solve, can u help me ?

140 semiconductor chips are inspected by choosing a sample of five chips. Assume 10 of the chips do not conform to customer requirements.

How many diffrent samples are possible -->140/5=28 am i right ?
and
How many samples of five contain exactly one nonconforming chip ?

Comment: You're answering the question of how many samples there will be if we continue to take five-chip samples from the original set without replacement. That is, if we take the $140$ chips and start putting them in boxes, five chips in each box, we'll fill $28$ boxes with no chips left over. But this result won't help  you find the probability that your first sample contains one of the nonconforming chips, which I strongly suspect is the point of this exercise. The answer $416,965,528$ (below) is more applicable to that probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if you have $n$ objects, and you want to choose $k$ of them, there are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to do so, where
$$ \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}.$$

So in your case $n= 140$ is the number of chips, and we want to take samples of size $k=5$, so there are $\binom{140}{5} = 416,965,528$ ways to sample the chips.

To count the number of samples (of size 5) containing exactly one of the 10 faulty chips: first select the faulty chip, there are $\binom{10}{1}=10$ ways to do this. Now choose any four chips from the remaining 130 working chips, there are $\binom{130}{4}$ ways for this, so in total there are
$$ \binom{10}{1} \binom{130}{4} = 10 * 11358880 = 113,588,800$$
possible choices.